# Objective-C UITableViewCell left/right/top/bottom space

Tags: iphone, uitableview, space, separator

How can i get this kind of UITableViewCells with left/right/top/bottom spacings?? It's almost same thing as used in Facebook app. 
Because I'm new here, I can't send pictures so here is link to look-alike aplication.

[See on this site, news.me application](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/lists/)

Comment: Which one is the Facebook app?  And what do you mean by spacings?  The empty space around the edges?  Just make the cell bigger and don't put anything close to the edges....

Comment: Facebook app from facebook. In their newsfeed (mainscreen) you see messages in some kind of "boxes", is that tableview or what ? Go to link i put in my question and see news.me application there and you will know what i'm talking about.

Comment: Looks like its possible by managing style of grouped UITableView ???

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, you want to have some custom tableViewCells. By subclassing UITableViewCell class you can customize it. You can add some background images and text labels wherever you want by setting their frame, so that you can obtain a box like view that you want to have. Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell).